# Automatically transferring a string from a Windows PC to a Linux server

Tags: linux, windows-10, raspberry-pi, mac-address, data-transfer

This is my current situation:

I have a PC running the latest Windows 10 and a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. On my PC I spoof my MAC address every other day. I always need the current MAC address of the Windows PC saved as a string in a JSON file on the Raspberry Pi. The automated process for this should get the most up-to-date MAC address in an interval of ~15 minutes (alternatively with a method to only send the new MAC address after it changes).

So now I'm looking for the easiest way to transfer the MAC as a string from Windows to Linux. I can't modify the program I use to spoof my MAC since it's closed source. The spoofing happens while the PC is running, not on startup or shutdown.

My ideas:

- Use a script on Windows that starts on boot and reads the MAC, then sends the string to the Raspberry Pi.
- Scan the network from the Pi and get the current MAC via the computer name that doesn't change.

I'm open for other ideas and methods to actually send the string to the Pi.

Comment: Why do you need to change the MAC address in the first place?

Comment: @Tetsujin The spoofing is part of a safety procedure to stay anonymous to a program that creates a fingerprint with a few other unique values on the PC. This is not the important part here though

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps on your pi:

1. ping the known hostname to get the windows pc IP address.
2. The ping will place the mac address of the Windows PC in your pi arp cache.  This assumes the pi and windows pc are on the same subnet.  You can then run arp -a to view the mac addresses in your arp cache of that IP address.

Something like:
arp -p | grep

should do it.

Comment: when I try to ping the hostname of my PC it gets resolved to an old IP that is not assigned anymore but still reserved so the output is: "Destination Host Unreachable". (After spoofing the MAC the PC gets a new IP through DHCP)

Comment: try running arp -d to erase the cache on the pi, then ping. What happens when you do that?

Comment: I can delete the arp entry for the PC hostname but when I try to ping it resolves to the same old IP again and the identical arp entry gets created

Comment: Do you change the MAC address only or change also the IP address ? Is the Windows PC referenced in a dynamic DNS ?

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer I change the MAC address and because of that the router sees my PC as a new device in the network and assigns a new local IP address

Comment: A static IP address would be compatible with a variable MAC address and a stable IP address. Usually DHCP routers don’t use higher address. Then in the range 192.168.1.2-192.168.1.254, you can use 192.168.1.200 or higher. (You don’t have an hundred of device, don’t you?). The safest way would be to reduce the DHCP range, but it is not always possible.

Comment: As @FrédéricLoyer suggests, see if you can map your two mac addresses to a single ip address in your router dhcp setup.  That would fix your changing ip address issue.  Or otherwise you could setup a fixed ip address for your pc.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer unfortunately the MAC address is always random, it's not just 2 different ones. Is there a way I can assign my PC a static IP any other way than by the MAC address (e.g. by hostname)?

Comment: On Windows, under the IPv4 properties, you can define a static address. The way to do access them depends of the version of Windows. You should mention it.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer I tried this and it worked, but the spoofing software resets the windows settings to DHCP so I get a new IP anyway